# Forcing discrete time series to be monotonous decreasing

Tags: r

I've an evaluations series. Each evaluation could have discrete values ranging from 0 to 4. Series should decrease in time. However, since values are inserted manually, errors could happen. 
Therefore, I would like to modify my series to be monotonous decreasing. Moreover, I would minimize the number of evaluations modified. Finally, if two or more series would satisfy these criteria,  would choose the one with the higher overall values sum.

E.g.

## Recorded evaluation

4332422111

## Ideal evaluation

4332222111

## Recorded evaluation

4332322111

## Ideal evaluation

4333322111 
(in this case, 4332222111 would have satisfied criteria too, but I chose with the higher values)

I tried with brutal force approach by generating all possible combinations, selecting those monotonous decreasing and finally comparing each one of these with that recorded.
However, series could be even 20-evaluations long and combinations would too many.

Comment: do you ever expect drops of >1?

Comment: Hi, Ben. Could happen.

Comment: What about the situation like this: 4443334222111?

Comment: In this case, both 3 and 2 could be suitable. However, we assume the series with the highest values as the preferable. Therefore, 3 should be the right substitution.

Answer (score 1):

```
x1 <- c(4,3,3,2,4,2,2,1,1,1)
x2 <- c(4,3,3,2,3,2,2,1,1,1)
```

You could almost certainly break this algorithm, but here's a first try: replace locations with increased values by NA, then fill them in with the previous location.

```
dfun <- function(x) {
    r <- replace(x,which(c(0,diff(x))>0),NA)
    zoo::na.locf(r)
}

dfun(x1)
dfun(x2)
```

This gives the "less-ideal" answer in the second case.

For the record, I also tried

```
dfun2 <- function(x) {
    s <- as.stepfun(isoreg(-x))
    -s(seq_along(x))
}
```

but this doesn't handle the first example as desired.

You could also try to do this with discrete programming (about which I know almost nothing), or a slightly more sophisticated form of brute force -- use a stochastic algorithm that strongly penalizes non-monotonicity and weakly penalizes the distance from the initial sequence ... (e.g. `optim(..., method="SANN")` with a candidate function that adds or subtracts 1 from an element at random)

Comment: Thank you, Ben. Actually, this doesn't solve completely the problem if more than one evaluation should be modified.

    x1 <- c(4,3,3,2,3,3,2,1,1,1)
With the ideal vector being:

    x1 <- c(4,3,3,3,3,3,2,1,1,1)
Thus, substituting the 2 rather than the two 3 (therefore minimizing the number of substitutions).

Comment: The responder did point out himself that this was only an approximation.